# sbt unmanagedResource directories move to different folder in the jar

Tags: sbt, playframework-2.2

I have to copy resources under app/ folder to classpath. This is what I did. But all files under app/assets/css will end up at assets/css in the jar. How can I tell sbt to move all app/assets to public folder in the jar.

```
  val assetsS = Seq(
      unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile <+= scalaSource in Compile,
      excludeFilter in unmanagedResources in Compile := "*.scala" || "*.java" || "*.js" || "*.less" || "*.coffee"
    )
```